# What is the difference between using filter vs loc to select only certain columns?

Tags: pandas

df.filter(items=["A","D"])

vs

df.loc(:,["A","D"])

What is the difference between the above options to select all rows from 2 columns?

When should I use filter and when should I used loc?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the filtering capabilities provided by the `filter` method (see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)), the `loc` method is much faster.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"X":np.random.random((1000,)),
                  })

%%timeit
df.filter(items=['X'])
```

```
Out:
    87.5 µs ± 2.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
df.loc[:,'X']
```

```
Out:
    8.52 µs ± 69.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: So when would I choose to use filter, instead of loc?

Comment: If you just need to select specific columns with names you know, then it's better to use loc